# Need an Easier Version of This Python Script

Tags: python, optimization, probability

so I just started learning python after a bit of C++ and we are finding probabilities of dice rolls on python. My question is, if there is a better version of this code that is much simpler and "obvious":

```
def numsix(roll):
  return len([dice for dice in roll if dice == 6])

sample = [[i] for i in range(1,7)]
for i in range(7):
      sample = [x + [i] for x in sample for i in range (1,7)] 

event = [roll for roll in sample if numsix(roll)==4]
print(len(event), "/" ,len(sample))
```

Comment: Where do you see any hate because of the missing spaces? There is criticism because of a quite unclear and broad qustion.

Comment: I need a better version of the code above. I'm still fairly new to coding, isn't this website made for such purpose?

Answer (score 0):

Well,

I made another longer but clearer version of the code. This code and the one above calculates the probability of **having four sixes when we roll eight dice** 
Here's v2 of the code:

```
def numSix(roll):
  return len([dice for dice in roll if dice == 6])

r = range(1,7)
sample = [(i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p) for i in r for j in r for k in r for l in r \
                            for m in r for n in r for o in r for p in r]
event = [roll for roll in sample if numSix(roll) == 4]

print (len(event), "/" ,len(sample))
```

Any other tips are welcome. Thanks for the criticism -__-.